# How to deploy Angular 15 app with iis that has multiple apps

Tags: angular, iis, angular15

I have tried changing the base href in index.html

```html
<base href="/AppName/">
```

I have also added, the rerouting config.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

 <system.webServer> 
  <rewrite> 
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url=".*" /> 
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" /> 
      </rule> 
    </rules> 
  </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

I have gone through all of the questions in stackoverflow but there is a lot of irrelevant, case related info out there, and none of them worked for me. I just need someone to tell me **do this and it will work**

It is insane to me that this info is not given in the docs, and we have to jump through questions and issues to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy the angular app in iis as application you can follow beelow steps:

1. Run below command to build the angular app:

ng build --base-href='/basepath/'

base path will be the same app name as iis application name

2. Create application in iis and point to the dist and your angular build path something like below:

C:\app-name\dist\app-name

3. Create web.config file as below at this path C:\app-name\dist\app-name:

   ```
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
   ```

Note: Do not forgot to assign iis_iusrs and iusr user permission to the site root folder

Comment: I upvoted for the effort but I solved my problem before this answer. I basically deleted AppName stuff from base href and added `</configuration>` to the bottom of the `web.config`. Built with `ng build` without any other param. I guess I didn't need to include base-href stuff since there was other apps in the iis but all of the sites had their own domain.